# How to get live data in excel from another excel file that's in dropbox or onedrive for mac

Tags: excel, dropbox

I'm struggling to find a way to link an excel workbook to another that is hosted online, in dropbox or onedrive.  I've actually achieved this with excel for PC using the dropbox api (but utilizes power query) but when testing on mac, the connections do not work. I believe power query is not supported on mac.

We are constantly updating the list of brands and stores we work with, so I want to create a file that has a link to these excel brand & store lists. This way reps working in the field can use my file (on mac or pc) and always have fresh store and brand data.

Thanks in advance, any insight is appreciated:)